# Can Not Deploy Compose Preview with Arctic Fox Stable

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I get this error when trying to deploy preview:

```
androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.PreviewActivity is not an Activity subclass or alias
```

[image: error pop up]

I got this error in both new clean project or old project. Here is what i use:

- AGP: 7.0.0 and 7.1.0-alpha03 do not work.
- Kotlin: 1.5.10  Compose: 1.0.0
- compileSdk and targetSdk: both 30 and 31 do not work
- Try use tooling with tooling-preview and only the tooling-preview, both do not work.

Comment: Did you try with AGP 7.1.0 alpha05?

Comment: alpha04 and 05 breaks my project, so im still using alpha03

Answer (score 1):

i got this too, very frustrating to see celebration when something so simple as running/previewing "Hello" template fails